# How to make a table from a dictionary with multiple content types in Swift?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have made an NSArray with NSDictionary objects containing contents downloaded from an api. I also made a tableview object on main.storyboard with a prototype cell with a UIImage label and two text labels as its contents. 
How can I put the data from array to table so that each cell with same style as my prototype shows contents of NSDictionary from the array.

Comment: is there anything that you already tried to solve this issue? It is often better received by the community if you can show some effort from your side.

Comment: parsing unstructured data is one of the more annoying tasks in swift at the moment. Take a look at some projects like [swiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for ideas.

Comment: Yes I tried searched everywhere to find solutions to similar issues but none of them worked for me and I'm working on it for like 2-3 hrs. I'm beginner in Swift.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to implement UITableViewDataSource methods
Remember to set dataSource property of tableView to ViewController
Than you get one object(your NSDictionary) from array and set cell labels and imageView with it's data.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Here is full Code example in `Swift`. Objective-C is very similar

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

   var objects = [
    ["name" : "Item 1", "image": "image1.png"],
    ["name" : "Item 2", "image": "image2.png"],
    ["name" : "Item 3", "image": "image3.png"]]

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text =  object["name"]!
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: object["image"]!)
    cell.otherLabel?.text =  object["otherProperty"]!

    return cell
  }

}
```