# How to load my data back from CoreDate to display it in tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, save

*I'm new to using CoreData - so I tried to set up an App where the User can save some text via button to the CoreData and load it back to display it in a tableView. I figured out how to save the data but I can't figure out how to load it back right. It has to be loaded when new information is stored and when the View load.*

```
class ViewControllerExercises: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func tappedAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newExercises = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Exercises", inManagedObjectContext: context ) as NSManagedObject
    newExercises.setValue(textField.text,forKey:"exercises")

    context.save(nil)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return exercises.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell

    var toDoItem:NSDictionary = exercises.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as NSDictionary
    cell.textLabel!.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("exercises") as? String

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
let toDoItem = exercises[indexPath.row]

cell.textLabel?.text =  toDoItem["exercises"]!
```

For more reference check this answer [How to make a table from a dictionary with multiple content types in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453675/how-to-make-a-table-from-a-dictionary-with-multiple-content-types-in-swift)

may be this will help you.